# EventMachine Proxy -- HTTP Proxy mixing up request/response pairs

Tags: ruby, proxy, eventmachine

I have the following code (just as a test) and I want to create an HTTP proxy using EventMachine. The code below is an example on the es-proxy GitHub page. However, when I run this and open up a website that has a moderate amount of images, the images start loading incorrectly. What I mean by this is that some images are loaded twice or if I request my icon for the navigation bar, I instead get the profile picture. This is especially evident if I refresh the page a few times.

It seems that the responses do not correspond to the matching request; causing everything to be jumbled. However, I'm not sure why this is. The code below seems simple enough for this to not be a problem.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'em-proxy'
require 'http/parser' # gem install http_parser.rb
require 'uuid'        # gem install uuid

# > ruby em-proxy-http.rb
# > curl --proxy localhost:9889 www.google.com

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 9889
puts "listening on #{host}:#{port}..."

Proxy.start(:host => host, :port => port) do |conn|

  @p = Http::Parser.new
  @p.on_headers_complete = proc do |h|
    session = UUID.generate
    puts "New session: #{session} (#{h.inspect})"

    host, port = h['Host'].split(':')
    conn.server session, :host => host, :port => (port || 80)
    conn.relay_to_servers @buffer

    @buffer = ''
  end

  @buffer = ''

  conn.on_connect do |data,b|
    puts [:on_connect, data, b].inspect
  end

  conn.on_data do |data|
    @buffer << data
    @p << data

    data
  end

  conn.on_response do |backend, resp|
    #puts [:on_response, backend, resp].inspect
    resp
  end

  conn.on_finish do |backend, name|
    puts [:on_finish, name].inspect
  end
end
```

**Update**

I believe I have insight as to what is happening but, still no way of solving my problem. I am creating a server for each request and when I relay my requests I have multiple servers. Then in the on response I should only be returning the response if it is from the correct server.  However, I don't have a way to correlate this as of yet.

Comment: I just tried the example given with em-proxy and it works fine for me. I just had to remove every puts to have acceptable performance (some images were corrupted before that).  Did you make some changes or are you using the examples as is ?

Comment: I'm using the example as is. Did you try going to google maps? And if you did can you do a cache-free refresh while the proxy is running. Is it still working? If so, what is your platform and ruby version. I am on Windows running 1.8.7

Comment: @Schmurfy -> Wow, you were right. I must have not read over the part in your comment about leaving out the `puts` statements. I find that very odd that it causes em-proxy to return corrupt images. I understand that it would be slower but corrupt? IDK. Hey, since you're suggestion worked, I'd be glad to accept and answer from you to give you credit if you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a proper response:

Try removing every puts in the example so the main loop can concentrate on doing the actual network I/O, it works for me like that.
I think there may be some kind of timeout playing behind this, maybe the client does not wait long enough for the full answer to come back while the server is stuck outputing text to the console.

That's the downside of using an event reactor, you have to make sure nothing blocks it.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't seem to account for persistent http connections. Maybe you could try a HTTP 1.0 browser.

Comment: Any suggestions for 1.0 browsers?

Comment: You should be able to set windows ie to use http 1.0 with proxy in internet options -> advanced